# What's the difference between includeJSFooter and Implementing JS in the Template ? (TYPO3)

Tags: javascript, typo3, typo3-8.x

I searched Google and Stackoverflow to find an Answer, but I found nothing that explains me the difference in Topic.

I want to know, what's the difference between:

1) including Javascript in TYPO3 with:

```
page.includeJSFooter.something = EXT:/mypath_to_javascript/something.js
```

2) and e.g. with :

```
<f:section name="FooterAssets">
   <script src="/typo3conf/ext/mypath_to_javascript/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</f:section>
```

I know there is a difference, because the source code looks unequal:

1) Sourcecode:

```
<script src="/typo3conf/ext/mypath_to_javascript/something.js?1521928758" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Sourcecode:

```
<script src="/typo3conf/ext/mypath_to_javascript/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

The **?1521928758** makes the difference, what means that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**?1521928758** is a timestamp, that makes sure that the browser doesn't serve a old version of a file. The timestamp is calculated from the file. So if you change the content of the file, the timstamp will change, and the browser will load the new version, instead what it might have cached locally

Comment: Perfect, thanks... so it's better to use the Method via includeJSFooter not the inlcude "via Sourcecode"-Variant?

Comment: I will say yes :-) And read the link from Joey above, it tells more and give some insight

Comment: I actually just upvoted his response, because the he gave gives more information and offers a solution for your posted issue

Answer (score 5):

The major difference is, that you can add specific parameters to the TypoScript version, that can not be handled by the Fluid version.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejsfooter-array

Especially when it comes to concatenation, compression and the order of files, that might depend on each other, you want to go for TypoScript, since it gives you lots of parameters to manage how JS will be handled.